# Iterate over a list of string tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples

```
[('fish', 100),
 ('cat', 1000),
 ('dog', 800)]
```

I want to take the first element of each tuple into a list.

```
animals = []
for i in data:
    animals.extend(i[0])
print(animals)
```

I received result like this `['f', 'i', 's', 'h', ' ', 'c', 'a', 't', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g']`

I was expecting `['fish', 'cat', 'dog']`

I'm able to print the ideal result with

```
for i in data:
    print(i[0])
```

But I would like to save the list.

Comment: You want to `append` not `extend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend will take the string a list, so try `.append()`:

```
animals = []
for i in data:
    animals.append(i[0])

print(animals)
```

Better is a list comprehension

```
animals = [i[0] for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `append` instead of `extend`. `extend` adds all the elements of iterable to the list.